# How do I identify members of a union in a C++ struct in Doxygen xml output

Tags: doxygen

When I generate xml output in Doxygen for C++ structs containing unions I can identify where the union ends but not where the union starts.  How does the xml output indicate where a union begins?

For example if I parse this D3D12 struct:

```
typedef struct D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER {
  D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE  Type;
  D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAGS Flags;
  union {
    D3D12_RESOURCE_TRANSITION_BARRIER Transition;
    D3D12_RESOURCE_ALIASING_BARRIER   Aliasing;
    D3D12_RESOURCE_UAV_BARRIER        UAV;
  };
} D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER;
```

I get a memberdef with a type that starts with union after the last member of the union, but that doesn't seem to contain enough information to identify the start of the union:

```
      <sectiondef kind="public-attrib">
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___b_a_r_r_i_e_r_1ab6ad811122cbe7f71a5f3675b54c59b4" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type><ref refid="d3d12__xs_8h_1ace7558c2b566b01eb8f0f974970462fd" kindref="member">D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE</ref></type>
        <definition>D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Type</definition>
        <argsstring></argsstring>
        <name>Type</name>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___b_a_r_r_i_e_r_1a1a1425ffd80baf51a5ad13a0eb2df11f" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type><ref refid="d3d12__xs_8h_1a513a291100449ffb8d68dde9c8baafaf" kindref="member">D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAGS</ref></type>
        <definition>D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAGS D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Flags</definition>
        <argsstring></argsstring>
        <name>Flags</name>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___b_a_r_r_i_e_r_1af2894e6907d168f85389eafad5ff4468" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type><ref refid="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___t_r_a_n_s_i_t_i_o_n___b_a_r_r_i_e_r" kindref="compound">D3D12_RESOURCE_TRANSITION_BARRIER</ref></type>
        <definition>D3D12_RESOURCE_TRANSITION_BARRIER D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition</definition>
        <argsstring></argsstring>
        <name>Transition</name>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___b_a_r_r_i_e_r_1af61e6bf0958d3c00262ca7fe992b175f" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type><ref refid="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___a_l_i_a_s_i_n_g___b_a_r_r_i_e_r" kindref="compound">D3D12_RESOURCE_ALIASING_BARRIER</ref></type>
        <definition>D3D12_RESOURCE_ALIASING_BARRIER D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Aliasing</definition>
        <argsstring></argsstring>
        <name>Aliasing</name>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___b_a_r_r_i_e_r_1ab8e70b55235a48bdd0e357f341bd233c" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type><ref refid="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___u_a_v___b_a_r_r_i_e_r" kindref="compound">D3D12_RESOURCE_UAV_BARRIER</ref></type>
        <definition>D3D12_RESOURCE_UAV_BARRIER D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::UAV</definition>
        <argsstring></argsstring>
        <name>UAV</name>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
      </memberdef>
      <memberdef kind="variable" id="struct_d3_d12___r_e_s_o_u_r_c_e___b_a_r_r_i_e_r_1ab309192116241523db001099c26eb3e6" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
        <type>union D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::@51</type>
        <definition>union D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::@51 D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::@52</definition>
        <argsstring></argsstring>
        <name>@52</name>
        <briefdescription>
        </briefdescription>
        <detaileddescription>
        </detaileddescription>
        <inbodydescription>
        </inbodydescription>
      </memberdef>
```

In this case I could probably identify the members of the union by looking for kindref="compound", but built in values like int don't have a ref inside the type field so that approach wouldn't work for all structures.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.1.

Comment: I did some tests and without giving the union a name I didn't succeed, looks like doxygen flattens the anonymous union. Mavbe best to file an enchantments issue in the doxygen repository on github.